# Graph drawing libraries using Raphael

Tags: javascript, graph, raphael, graph-drawing

I'm looking for javascript libraries that draw graphs using the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) library.

Until now I've found these ones:

1. Graph Dracula http://www.graphdracula.net/
2. Joint http://www.jointjs.com/

Is anyone using them? Do you know their pros/cons?
Do you know other libraries using Raphael?

Please note: By graph, I mean a set of nodes and edges, we are not talking about charting.

**edit: I need a library based on Raphael as it offers compatibility with IE6+, while other libraries draw on HTML5 Canvas and this is not supported by old browsers**

Comment: how about use google chrome frame installer in IE6/7/8 http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started#TOC-Detecting-Google-Chrome-Frame-and-P ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EXT.JS](http://www.sencha.com) is not free, but worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Google Visualization API Gadget Gallery](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gadgetgallery.html)

Its Playground link is http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization

Google provides API to load the flash based interactive graphs. I would consider this to better than the three option discovered because of its easy to use APIs and rich collection of graphs and last but not least rich look.

Comment: I was looking for Raphael based libraries because I need Raphael backward compatibility. So you didn't answer to my question